# Android. XML layouts and button references

Tags: android, layout

All projects I put into Eclipse do not read any of the layouts or button references I have.

Layout references like `(R.layout.main)` and button references like `(R.id.namebutton)`
all have a "cannot be resolved or is not a field" warning that applies to all button and layout references.

They all worked last night. I have all my XML files in the layout folder and each button has the `android:id="@+id/"` line in the XML. Yet the warnings remain.

What could it be causing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Zohan.hozo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ZohanActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>  
        <activity
        android:name=".MacAttack"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".ConsultationReq"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please write sentances starting with uppercase letters.

Comment: First try cleaning and rebuilding the project because sometimes the SDK just gets stuck. If that doesn't work, then look for errors in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Errors in there will prevent R from being automatically generated.

Comment: cleaning did not work, I added my manifest in case something looks  out of place to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, R.layout.* and R.id.* and all the R.* refer to an Android-SDK-generated class called R, which is to be in gen/. In case it is not you may have:
- errors in your xml layout files
- errors in your android manifest file
- errors elsewhere.

In case you HAD errors in these files, that you fixed them and it still doesn't work, try project->clean in Eclipse, that should update the dependencies.

Comment: I indeed dont have it in my gen/ folder, I looked in other projects and the gen/ has a R.java file. I see lines in R.java like     "public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;" Im a assuming the numbers that ic_launcher is equal to tells the R where its located. Is there a way I can do this manually where I can finally get rid of these warnings? Because I deleted the import android.R; and now all of the R's have warnings now

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you are accidentally importing android.R? Sometimes this line appears when you do Ctrl+Shift+O to fix imports:

import android.R;

This line should NOT be there (unless you put it there intentionally for a reason). This will cause "R" to reference the built-in Android resources rather than your app's resources.

Comment: what do I do when I remove import android.R; and now I have all my R's labeled with warnings

Comment: highlight one of the R's and it should show you options including import your.package.name.R, this is the one you want.